# Ignore exceptions when executing bytecode (java)?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have a large program, that i modified in java. I used the intelliJ idea (community edition) IDE for compiling. When i go to run the program, it starts up the GUI and then proceeds to do everthing i want from it, with very few problems (of which are unrelated to the exceptions). But the code always generates class not found exceptions (even the original unmodified code does this once you extract it from the .jar file. Despite these errors, it executes within the IDE perfectly, while still noting the errors, but they don't appear to have an effect on the program. However, when i execute them from within the virtual machine (with java filename) the exceptions which are usually ignored prevent the ultimate execution of the program. The errors are exactly the same as the ones that the iDE shows, but the IDE ignores them! How could i get a virtual machine to ignore the errors and execute the program (is there an option to pass to java - for example java -ignoreerrors filename).

Is this possible, or will i have to alter the code?

Comment: "always generates class not found exceptions"  Are you getting `ClassNotFoundException`s or `ClassNotFoundError`s?

Comment: You're kidding - you want the JVM to simply ignore errors/exceptions? Did you start the application inside the IDE in some kind of debug mode?

Comment: sorry, i should have probably made an edit, was exceptions, is now errors

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to ignore ClassNotFoundExceptions unless that class isn't actually needed by the code. Some frameworks do that by trying to load a class to discover whether some feature is available. However, if a CNFE is preventing your app from running, you'll just have to fix it. If you show some stack traces, someone might be able to steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with `ClassNotFoundException`s then you can always localize the problem and catch and log using `try { ... } catch (...) { ... }`.

If you are instead getting `ClassNotFoundError`s then it's not a localizable problem with reflection, but a failure to initialize code that's needed.  You should try to prune unneeded dependencies but you really shouldn't use classes that haven't initialized properly.

If you absolutely have to, you can always load your program using a [custom `ClassLoader`](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Security/Fundamentals/magercises/ClassLoader/help.html) that generates bogus empty classes for any name that is not resolvable using the system classloader and use that to load your main class.  That will replicate, to some degree, what your IDE is doing, though your IDE probably goes the extra step to make sure that partially well-defined classes have the right interface even if some methods are stubbed out because their bodies don't compile.

Comment: thank you, this makes sense. The unmodified bytecode came inside a jar, i am probably missing the class loader file. i will try to write my own. (or find the original)

Comment: what situations would cause a specialized class loader? will intelliJ idea (my IDE) be able to make the file for me (seeing as it seemed to do it in order to execute the code)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can only ignore compiler warnings. You cannot ignore errors.
2. The errors that IntelliJ shows are coming from the same compiler.
3. `ClassNotFoundException` would indicate that your code failed to dynamically load a class at runtime.
4. This could mean that a required dependency (jar) is missing from your classpath. Try to consult your code documentation and make sure you've resolved all runtime dependencies. Also make sure that the dependent jars are in the classpath otherwise the runtime won't be able to find them.